# How do I automatically fix lint issues reported by pylint?

Tags: python, pylint

Just like we have ["eslint --fix"](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface) to automatically fix lint problems in Javascript code, do we have something for [pylint](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint) too for Python code?

Comment: This is an old question, but voting to reopen as I don't really think it is seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, etc; it's simply asking `pylint` has a way to automatically fix issues it finds- I was wondering the same thing and found this question.

Comment: Pylint (still) don't have the feature to auto fix, but today there are other alternatives like Ruff (id:charliermarsh.ruff) that can fix things. For an existing codebase with many lint errors, running for example Ruff can give you a running start in fixing all these errors. After that you can continue using Ruff, or switch to Pylint depending on your preferences.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Some of the formatting-errors reported by `pylint` can be fixed with [autopep8](https://github.com/hhatto/autopep8), [black](https://github.com/psf/black), or the built-in formatting supported by PyCharm and other IDEs.

Comment: Here is an example command using `autopep8`: `autopep8 --in-place --aggressive --aggressive *.py`

Comment: @TylerChong That example does not work in version 1.6.0 as it does not recognize *.py. Could you please provide an updated command that checks all files?

Comment: autopep8 fixes only a small number of the errors reported by pylint. My code had a 1.95/10 rating after autopep8, with previous run at 0.39/10.

Comment: AutoPep8 works well enough for me ( I am able to use the custom rules from the internal Google pylintrc file) from this link: https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html

Answer (score 5):

You also have [black](https://github.com/psf/black) now. Both `black` and `autopep8` can be integrated into most good editors.

Comment: Unfortunately `black` fixes only a small number of the errors reported by `pylint`, even when combined with `autopep8`.

Comment: Isn't Black highly opinionated? It would not work with a custom Pylintrc script, right?

Answer (score 3):

There is also [autoflake](https://pypi.org/project/autoflake/) which removes unused variables and imports.

Note that it only removes unused imports from the standard library by default, to ensure that there are no side-effects.

Example usage:

```bash
autoflake -r --in-place --remove-unused-variables src/
```