# Is there a linter that provides auto fixes for lint failures like eslint?

Tags: python, static-analysis, pylint, flake8

eslint has an api ([docs](https://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/working-with-rules#applying-fixes)) that allows lints to provide fixes for a lint error. So by running `eslint --fix`, issues like missing semi-colons can be fixed automatically.

I couldn't find anything like this for flake8 or pylint.

Is there a Python linter that has an API to build automatic fixes for a lint?

There is a related issue that is asking only about auto fixing formatting issues: [How do I automatically fix lint issues reported by pylint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54586757/how-do-i-automatically-fix-lint-issues-reported-by-pylint)

EDIT:

I'm not interested in formatting specifically. I'm interested in finding an API equivalent to eslint that enables me to build lints and automatic fixes for those lints

Comment: Are you looking for a code formatter? Like the black?

Comment: I'm looking for a general linter that enables me to build lints and automatic fixes for those lints, like eslint.

Comment: Try reposting your question on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/